# How can I return a result from inner anonymous class before the function returns the result?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, microsoft-account

I'm using Microsoft's msal library to have users sign in to their account. I'm using MVVM so I need to the function to return a `Resource<String>` but the function is returning a value before the msal callbacks are being invoked and updating the value I need to return. I've tried:

1. Using `CoroutineScope(IO).launch {}` and running the sign-in function in there but that does not return asynchronously.
2. Using `CoroutineScope(IO).async {}` and then return@async Resource inside the callback. I'm compiler complains since the callback is void type.
3. Using Kotlin FLow<Resource> and emit value from inside the callback.

Can anyone help me out with any ideas of how to get this to run asynchronously or return a value from within the callbacks? Thanks!

```
suspend fun microsoftSignIn(activity: Activity): Resource<String> {
    var resource: Resource<String> = Resource.Error(Throwable(""))
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(context, R.raw.auth_config_single_account, object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
                override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication?) {
                    application?.signIn((activity as AllActivityBase), null, Array(1) {"api://ScopeBlahBlah"}, object : AuthenticationCallback {
                        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult?) {
                            Log.i("TOKEN_MSAL ${authenticationResult?.accessToken}" )
                            authenticationResult?.accessToken?.let { storeToken(it) }
                            ///// I need this to run first before "return resource" runs!!! /////
                            resource = Resource.Success("Success")
                        }

                        override fun onCancel() {
                            resource = Resource.Error(Throwable(""))
                        }

                        override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {=
                            resource = Resource.Error(Throwable(""))
                        }

                    })
                }

                override fun onError(exception: MsalException?) {
                    Log.i("TOKEN_MSAL_A EX ${exception?.message}")
                    resource = Resource.Error(Throwable(""))
                }

            })
    }
    return resource
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to consume a traditional asynchronous API and make it suspendable, the easiest is to use either [suspendCoroutine()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) or [CompletableDeferred](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/). I can't easily reuse your code, so I will provide you just a generic solution, but it should be easy for you to adjust it to your needs.

`suspendCoroutine()`:

```
suspend fun test1(): String {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            doSomethingAsync(object : Callback {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                    cont.resume("success")
                }

                override fun onError() {
                    cont.resume("error")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

`CompletableDeferred`:

```
suspend fun test2(): String {
    val result = CompletableDeferred<String>()
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        doSomethingAsync(object : Callback {
            override fun onSuccess() {
                result.complete("success")
            }

            override fun onError() {
                result.complete("error")
            }
        })
    }
    return result.await()
}
```

As you can see, both solutions are pretty similar. I'm not sure if there are any big differences between them. I guess not, so use whichever you like more.

Also, in both cases you can throw an exception instead of returning an error. You can use `resumeWithException()` for the first example and `completeExceptionally()` for the second.

One final note: you used `Dispatchers.IO` in your example, so I did the same, but I doubt it is needed here. Asynchronous operations don't block the thread by definition, so it should be ok to run them from any dispatcher/thread.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, you are right, I updated my answer :-)

Comment: If `doSomethingAsync` actually were a blocking function, it wouldn't be valid to use `suspendCoroutine` to call it, because then `suspendCoroutine` would be blocking, which breaks the convention that suspend functions must never block. It might work with how you're wrapping it in `withContext` (which for a correctly non-blocking suspend function call is pointless), but I don't know if it could possibly tie up a thread that it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for this answer is exactly what I needed! Using the CompletableDeferred is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

To convert a callback-based function into something you can use properly in coroutines, you need to use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. Assuming your code above is correct (I'm not familiar with msal), it should look something like this. You have two callbacks to convert. These are top-level utility functions that you can put anywhere in your project:

```
suspend fun createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(
    context, 
    @RawRes authConfig: Int
): ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(context, authConfig, object : IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener {
        override fun onCreated(application: ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication) {
            continuation.resume(application)
        }

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
        }
    })
}

suspend fun ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.signInOrThrow(
    activity: AllActivityBase, // or whatever type this is in the API
    someOptionalProperty: Any?, // whatever this type is in the API
    vararg args: String
): IAuthenticationResult = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    signIn(activity, someOptionalProperty, args, object: : AuthenticationCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(authenticationResult: IAuthenticationResult) {
            continuation.resume(authenticationResult)
        }

        override fun onCancel() = continuation.cancel()

        override fun onError(exception: MsalException) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
        }
    })
}
```

Then you can use this function in any coroutine, and since it's a proper suspend function, you don't have to worry about trying to run it asynchronously or specifying Dispatchers.

Usage might look like this, based on what I think you were doing in your code:

```
suspend fun microsoftSignIn(activity: Activity): Resource<String>
    try {
        val application = createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(context, R.raw.auth_config_single_account)
        val authenticationResult = application.signInOrThrow((activity as AllActivityBase), null, "api://ScopeBlahBlah")
        Log.i(TAG, "TOKEN_MSAL ${authenticationResult.accessToken}" )
        authenticationResult.accessToken?.let { storeToken(it) }
        return Resource.Success("Success")
    } catch (e: MsalException) {
        return Resource.Error(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Other answer is short and to-the-point. Just posting this overly detailed one because I was mostly through writing it.